# No Data Returned From Delta Table Although Delta Files Exist

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I created a delta table in `Databricks` using `sql` as:

```
%sql
create table nx_bronze_raw
(
  `Device` string
)
USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/Databricks/bronze/devices/';
```

Then I ingest data (device column) into this table using:

```
bronze_path = '/mnt/Databricks/bronze/devices/'
df.select('Device').write.format("delta").mode("append").save(bronze_path)
```

The underlying storage is `Azure Blob Storage`, and the `Databricks` runtime is 12.1

The problem is when I query this table it returns 0 records:

```
df_read = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/Databricks/bronze/devices/")
display(df_read )

Query returned no results
```

Although, when I look inside the storage account, the delta files are created with the expected size:
[image]

What went wrong in this scenario, especially no error is returned ? and why can't I retrieve the data ?

Comment: do `display(spark.sql("describe history delta.\`/mnt/Databricks/bronze/devices/\`"))`

Comment: The result shows the history of the table, first operation is CREATE TABLE and the second is WRITE. But what can I get from that ?

Comment: you should see the number of records written

Comment: How do you get source data that you write into Delta?

Comment: what you are getting in `numFiles` under **operationMetrices** when display delta table [history](https://i.imgur.com/X6v8fPf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the possible reasons for getting empty results.

- If you are having empty dataset.

[image]

- If you truncate the table in between writing and reading the table.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

In this case, you can `describe` history of table and retrieve data of specific version.

[image]

Here, selecting the version before it is truncated.

```
df_read = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf",3).load("/mnt/Databricks/bronze/devices2/")
display(df_read )
```

[image]

- There is a chance that, the data has been written to the Delta files but hasn't been flushed to the table yet. To ensure that all changes are visible, you can try running `OPTIMIZE`

code:

```
%sql
optimize raw;
```

[image]